# How to save this in a JS variable?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to save the output of this into a "var a="

```
navigator.plugins.refresh(false);

var numPlugins = navigator.plugins.length;


for (var i = 0; i < numPlugins; i++){
  var plugin = navigator.plugins[i];

  if (plugin) {
    document.write(plugin.name + plugin.description + plugin.filename)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare `a` outside of the loop and define it as an empty string, then append results to it as you go:

```
navigator.plugins.refresh(false);

var numPlugins = navigator.plugins.length;
var a = '';

for (var i = 0; i < numPlugins; i++){
  var plugin = navigator.plugins[i];

  if (plugin) {
    a += plugin.name + plugin.description + plugin.filename;
  }
}
```

You may want to use an array of strings though, since you could have many plugins:

```
navigator.plugins.refresh(false);

var numPlugins = navigator.plugins.length;
var a = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numPlugins; i++){
  var plugin = navigator.plugins[i];

  if (plugin) {
    a.push(plugin.name + plugin.description + plugin.filename);
  }
}
```

**EDIT** If you need to hash `a` into something:

```
var hash = yourMd5Function(a);
```

Or for the second example:

```
var b = a.join(','); // "plugin1,plugin2,..." for example
var hash = yourMd5Function(b);
```

Comment: Thank you, what I need though is your first example. I have two comments. The output gives me a "undefined" at the begining, and then correctly shows the plugins.
The second comment is that I want to md5 the variable at the end. Not every time a plugin is added, but at the end.

Comment: Or a hash, to convert it into a series of number I prefer.

Comment: @Fataoulas: I edited to hopefully get rid of the `undefined` issue. To MD5 it at the end you'll need to find an implementation of that algorithm somewhere -- certainly you won't want to write that one yourself.